# UWP Custom Sqlite Query to JSON

Tags: c#, uwp, sqlite.net

I'm searching for a way to Execute Custom SQL Queries and to provide the result in JSON. Normally you have to provide a Class for the Query result e.g.

```
var query = dbConn.Query<ClassTypes>("Select a as key, b as value FROM table WHERE id = ?", new object[] { ObjectID });
```

But in my case, I don't know the SQL Statement, because its provided by an external JavaScript from a Webview.

This Webview might ask my application to Execute

```
Select a.col1 as foo,b.col1, a.col2 FROM table1 a INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.id=b.aid
```

And wants me to return:

```
foo:xxx
col2:yyy
```

Which columns are "asked" by the SQL Statement is completely free, or which aliases are used, I just want to execute the Statement an return key value pairs with the aliases or column names and the values in a JSON (for each row).

So I'm not able to prepare a custom Class for the Query, because I don't know the format of the SQL Query.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Do you used `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` to Query the database right?

Comment: You probably want to mention what is that `Query` method you had? What returns types/overloads supported etc? It looks like Dapper, but I can't confirm.

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to execute the Statement an return key value pairs with the aliases or column names and the values in a JSON (for each row).

For your scenario, You could use `SqlDataReader` to approach, `SqlDataReader` contains [`GetName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getname?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlDataReader_GetName_System_Int32_) method that could use to get the column name as key, and it also contains [`GetSqlValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getsqlvalue?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlDataReader_GetSqlValue_System_Int32_) method  that could retrieve column's value. If you can't confirm the field count, you could also use [`FieldCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.fieldcount?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlDataReader_FieldCount) to get current reader 's field counts

For example

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = GetProductsQuery;
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                var list = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    var i = 0;
                    do
                    {
                        var key = reader.GetName(i);
                        var value = reader.GetSqlValue(i);
                        dict.Add(key, value);
                        i++;
                    } while (i < reader.FieldCount);
                    list.Add(dict);       
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For more detail please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sql-server-databases).